# How to set Cookie on Fancybox Close Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, fancybox

I have the script below that works, but it activates the cookie on load. How do I get the cookie to activate only when the close button is clicked? On the "OnLoad.html" page I have a close button and a link button. I only want the cookie to load when the close button is clicked.

I did try the suggestion in the question titled "Setting cookie on click fancybox close button" and it did not work at all.

Thank you.

```
$(function() {
    if ($.cookie('test')) {
    } 
    else {     
       // set cookie to expire in x days
       $.cookie('test', 'true', { expires: 50 * 365 });
        $.fancybox( {
            href : 'example.com/OnLoad.html',
            type: 'ajax',
            helpers:  {
                overlay : null
            },
            keys : {
                close  : null
            },   
            closeBtn    : false,
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should *link* to other questions; finding by title is not particularly efficient. (You should also explain *why* other potential solutions did not work, or the question may be closed as a duplicate.)

Comment: move `$.cookie('test', 'true', { expires: 50*365});` inside the `afterClose` callback

Comment: Thank you JFK, worked perfectly! Sorry if I did not follow protocol by not linking to another post and just referencing it. I was not aware of all the features available here. Thank you again for your quick help JFK!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery

```
$("<YOUR-SELECTOR>").fancybox({
  onClosed: function() {
   $.cookie('test', 'true', { expires: 50*365});
  })
});
```

then create the cookie on session.php

Comment: read the question again, the OP already has a cookie (js) script running not php